# ANDROID BLE WRITE DATA

Tags: android, android-ble

I  currently working on  android app, i wan to  add BLE application in to my app,
that is , i wanna send data into  nrf51822/8001.

Please provide me a simple example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official tutorial here :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html
it will explain everything you need to know (scan, connexion and read/write..)

First you will need a BluetoothAdapter : 
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
        (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

To get devices arround you you have to perform a scan(don t forget to stop it when you find the device because it takes lot of resources)
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

To do the connexion use connectGatt(context, boolean connection auto,BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback)
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);

In the tutotial they use a Services to get update when there is a new device, or a new connection or when read/write.

You can ddl the projet here :
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/cefd49aae65dc85161d08419494071d74ffb982f/samples/BluetoothLeGatt

for read and write, go check about services, characteristics and UUID

Comment: please add some content from the tutorial

Comment: I edit my post with the most important steps, if you need more details please ask about a specific part.

Comment: Dagnogo Jean-François: Thank you. i can only able to send 5 byte data, i need to  send up to 16 byte data. please help me.

Comment: @NufailAchath I don't know why it does that. but tried to slit your data and send after. For me i just needed to read and it can read more than 5 bytes

Comment: @DagnogoJean-François: Thank you . Now i can able to send more than 5byte data.